# Missing opening after foreach keyword

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a problem with `foreach` loop. I'm trying to print the strings which are not present in the file. The code snippet throws error at `foreach` loop stating Missing opening `'('` after `foreach` keyword.How to overcome this error.

The strings to be searched are 'nature','kite','venue','street','venture' in the file abc.txt.

I have the following code snippet

```
$Pattern = @('nature|kite|venue|street|venture')
$Test = (Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches)
$Test = foreach {$_.matches.Value}
$t = $Pattern -split('\|')|where{$Test -notcontains $_}
```

Comment: [`foreach ($<item> in $<collection>){<statement list>}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Your ForEach loop has Curly Brackets, but still unsure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It thinks it's the other foreach.  I think you want `$Test = $Test | foreach ($_.matches.Value}`.  Otherwise, what is $_ referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go a different way:

- having an array of strings,
- build a Regular Expression by joining them with a `|`
- `Sort-Object -Unique` of the `Select-String` results

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\07\SO_56488287.ps1
$strings = @('nature','kite','venue','street','venture')
$Pattern = [RegEx]($strings -join '|')
$file    = '.\file.txt'

$Found = (Get-Content -Path $file |
          Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches
         ).Matches.Value | Sort-Object -Unique

$Missing = $Strings | Where {$Found -notcontains $_}

if($Missing){
    "Strings missing in $file"
    $Missing
} else {
    "All strings present in $file"
}
```

Comment: your solution lists all the strings as missing strings in output. How to overcome the solution?

Comment: the same code snippet doesnt work in powershell 2.0

Comment: If PowerShell-v2.0 is a requirement, you should explicitly use that tag [tag:powershell-v2.0] and/or mention in your question. The cmdlet ` Select-String` is post version 2. I'll think about a v2 solution.

Comment: I was able to get the solution.                                                                 $Found = Get-Content -Path $file |
         Select-String -Pattern $strings -AllMatches |
         Select-Object -Expand Matches |
         Select-Object -Expand Value

Comment: Well, in PowerShellv3+ (which has Select-String) my above solution does work also.

Comment: Yes @LotPings, your solution works in powershell v3+

Answer (score 1):

```
$Test = (Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches) | foreach {$_.matches.Value}
foreach ($t in $Test) {
    $Pattern -split('\|')|where{$Test -notcontains $_}
}
```

Comment: This will list ***all*** missing strings repeatedly, once per ***each*** found string (also if strings occur multiple times).